# jquery check a number onBlur

Tags: jquery

I have lots of the following textfields on a form, obviously their ids will all be different, but they are all type `currency2`.

```
<input class="form-control line_item_input not-assigned check-numeric" id="item_line_items_attributes_0_agency_single" name="item[line_items_attributes][0][agency_single]" type="currency2" value="1.5">
```

OnBlur - if the user has entered an invalid number such as 34.55.66.77 I want to change to 0.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has a very handy `$.isNumeric` helper function which you can utilize in this instance. Try this:

```
$('.check-numeric').blur(function() {
    if (!$.isNumeric(this.value))
        this.value = 0;
});
```

[$.isNumeric documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)

Comment: How would I use this with the textfields with a type of currency2?  and allow commas too!

Comment: Also if I tab out of a blank field it puts zero in

Comment: "currency2" isn't exactly a recognized HTML input type. While most browsers will render it as a text input I don't suggest using this "type". I would stick with Rory's example of using the .check-numeric selector.